# How to Route email objects from office 365 to custom SMTP proxy?

Tags: smtp, office365

I am trying to look for a way to get the email object from office 365 to route it to my SMTP proxy so that i can do further processing on the email object before it reaches the inbox of the recipient. Any help on this is much appreciated !

Thanks
Bharath

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an outbound connector in EOP: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj723138(v=exchg.150).aspx